# scroll eventlistener is interupting the scrolling event it triggers

Tags: reactjs, addeventlistener, use-effect

I have a event listener triggering a auto scroll event. however the auto scroll is triggering the event listener again which messes up the transition. How can I temporarily disable the listener while the auto scroll happens? Here is the listener:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
            scroll.scrollToBottom();//animated scroll to bottom of page
          });
    }, [])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating and removing the event listener:

```js
const scrollToMainContent = () => {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollToMainContent);
        scroll.scrollToBottom();
}
useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollToMainContent);
}, [])
```